# Location of UITableViewController files

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have multiple tableviews that have various static cells and everything is cool.

I would like to implement some functionality to a button that is in one of the cells in all of the tables, but I do not know where the header and implementation files for `UITableViewController` are located and or how to access them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly manipulate `UITableViewController`. Besides, it is not a good idea to do it anyway. The best way to do it is subclassing it.

1. Command+N and create a new `NSObject` file
2. When prompted, name it whatever you like (e.g. `MyTableViewController`)
3. Click on `MyTableViewController.h` in left side pane, and change `NSObject` to `UITableViewController`.
4. Goto the XIB file or the Storyboard (whichever you are using) and change the class of your `UITableViewController` to `MyTableViewController`.
5. Give a number to the button's `tag` field (e.g. 1001).
6. Now, in your MyTableViewController.m class, get a hold of the cell (`cellAtIndexPath:`) and then get a hold of that button with tag (`[cell.contentView viewWithTag:]`).